# Elasticsearch `match_bool_prefix` query and similar ones

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

In the [Elasticsearch documentation of the `match_bool_prefix` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-bool-prefix-query.html), it is stated that the query

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_bool_prefix" : {
      "message" : "quick brown f"
    }
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should": [
        { "term": { "message": "quick" }},
        { "term": { "message": "brown" }},
        { "prefix": { "message": "f"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I find very useful the possibility of having a query break the input into tokens automatically, but I have two questions:

1. Assuming the field `message` is a regular text field, isn't it "wrong" to use term queries with it? Shouldn't they be match queries instead?
2. What would be equivalent queries (similar to `match_bool_prefix` with `message: "quick brown f"`) to the following three queries? Also, do all three make sense?

Query A:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "message": "quick" }},
        { "match": { "message": "brown" }},
        { "prefix": { "message": "f"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Query B:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should": [
        { "term": { "message": "quick" }},
        { "term": { "message": "brown" }},
        { "term": { "message": "f"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Query C:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "message": "quick" }},
        { "match": { "message": "brown" }},
        { "match": { "message": "f"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

UPDATE: Is it possible that Query C is just a simple match query?